# Check only specific information from the orders post meta data in Woocommerce

Tags: php, sql, wordpress, woocommerce, orders

I am currently working on a WordPress project that has the WooCommerce plugin on it for the store. However all the billing info from orders go to the wp_postmeta table, where the all of the info is saved in the same column, "meta_value".

I have a form, that a customer can fill out using their order number, first name and post number, and after filing this field their order would show on the site.

Hence in my query I would only like to check if the user inputted order number, first name and post number are true, and I don't need anything else from the column.

I have made a test order with my credentials and at the moment my query looks like this, but it finds two results because there are two fields in the wp_postmeta table that have the same order number and the same first name in them as the order:

```
$ordernumber = $_POST['ordernmbr'];
$orderfirstname = $_POST['firstname'];
$orderpostnumber = $_POST['postnmbr'];

$sql = $wpdb->prepare( "SELECT * FROM {$wpdb->prefix}postmeta
WHERE post_id = %d AND meta_value = %s",
$ordernumber, $orderfirstname);
$res = $wpdb->get_results($sql, ARRAY_A);
```

Ask me if anything was unclear, I'm pretty bad at explaining things!

EDIT: Updated query after getting help from Vel, still not working as intended as the query doesn't want to find any results.

```
$sql = $wpdb->prepare( "SELECT * FROM {$wpdb->prefix}postmeta
WHERE post_id = %d AND (meta_value = %s AND meta_key  ='_billing_first_name' AND  meta_value = %s AND meta_key ='_billing_postcode') ",
$ordernumber, $orderfirstname, $orderpostnumber );
$res = $wpdb->get_results($sql, ARRAY_A);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you guys for all the help, but I actually managed to solve it by myself:

```
$sql = $wpdb->prepare("SELECT post_id FROM wp_postmeta
WHERE post_id = %d AND meta_key in ('_billing_first_name', '_billing_postcode')
and meta_value in ('%s', '%d')

group by post_id", $ordernumber, $orderfirstname, $orderpostnumber);
```

Answer (score 2):

The following SQL query will check if an entry exist for the given order ID, first name and post code:

```
$ordernumber = $_POST['ordernmbr'];
$orderfirstname = $_POST['firstname'];
$orderpostnumber = $_POST['postnmbr'];

$result = $wpdb->get_col( $wpdb->prepare( "
    SELECT pm.post_id
    FROM $wpdb->postmeta as pm
    JOIN $wpdb->postmeta as pm1 ON pm.post_id = pm1.post_id
    WHERE pm.post_id = %d
    AND pm.meta_key  ='_billing_first_name'
    AND pm.meta_value = %s
    AND pm1.meta_key ='_billing_postcode'
    AND pm1.meta_value = %s
", $ordernumber, $orderfirstname, $orderpostnumber ) );

if( sizeof($result) ) 
    $result = true;
```

Tested and works.

---

It can be also done with `get_post_meta()` Wordpress function this way:

```
$firstname = get_post_meta( $_POST['ordernmbr'], '_billing_first_name', true );
$postnmbr  = get_post_meta( $_POST['ordernmbr'], '_billing_postcode', true );

if( $firstname == $_POST['firstname'] && $postnmbr == $_POST['postnmbr'] ) {
    // The data match
} elseif( $firstname == $_POST['firstname'] || $postnmbr == $_POST['postnmbr'] ) {
    // The data match partially
else {
    // The data don't match
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use meta_key.

```
$ordernumber = $_POST['ordernmbr'];
$orderfirstname = $_POST['firstname'];
$orderpostnumber = $_POST['postnmbr'];

$sql = $wpdb->prepare( "select * from (SELECT * FROM wp_postmeta WHERE ( meta_key = '_billing_first_name' AND meta_value =%s ) 
OR ( meta_key = '_shipping_postcode' AND meta_value =%s ) ) as p 
where post_id=%s", $orderfirstname, $orderpostnumber, $ordernumber );
$res = $wpdb->get_results($sql, ARRAY_A);
```

**updated query**

```
select * from (SELECT * FROM wp_postmeta WHERE ( meta_key = '_billing_first_name' AND meta_value ='Gnanavel' ) OR ( meta_key = '_shipping_postcode' AND meta_value ='622222' ) ) as p where post_id=2899
```

[image]

Comment: Is there any chance for you to explain why the the meta_value and meta_key are in brackets?

Comment: Also, is it possible to do this same thing right after, but with the postcode? I tried but the query doesn't want to print anything.

Comment: as in, I am trying to get the query find BOTH the first name of the customer and the billing postcode, but with just the part you showed me, the query only looks at the first name part and doesn't care about the postcode at all. Is there a way to do it so that it looks at the postcode as well?

Comment: It can be found there in the same place as the customer name, yes

Comment: Tried that way, changed the correct variables and values but the query is not getting any results :/

Comment: Edited to original post to show what the query looks like right now

Comment: Could you elaborate by any chance? Since I am not quite sure what you mean.

Comment: i have update custom query. `select * from (SELECT * FROM wp_postmeta WHERE ( meta_key = '_billing_first_name' AND meta_value ='vel' ) OR ( meta_key = '_shipping_postcode' AND meta_value ='67801' ) ) as p where post_id=2899`